# Would it be possible to construct a stand-alone grass.script python package?

Tags: python, grass-gis

I would like to migrate dependency on ArcPy to grass.script without requiring the full installation of Grass. Would it be technically possible to have a portable directory containing grass.script and all the libraries it depends upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally yes - you "just" need to figure out the dependencies. The GRASS user mailing list may help you in case of troubles.

PS: Please post your results to http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python then for the rest of the world. Thanks!